# Mobile Status Update Not Visible to Everyone on Facebook

Tags: facebook, mobile, status

My FB privacy setting allows everyone to see my status update. This works perfectly when I update my FB status using a computer. However, when the update is done via mobile device, it is only visible to my FB friends, not to everyone as originally intended.

When I logon to FB via a computer, I can see there is a padlock icon after my mobile update. The icon is not there when I update the status via the computer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Long shot because I don't have facebook on my mobile now, but did you checked the options on your mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to find out why when I update my status via SMS it was shared with 'Only Me' and have just found out why:

Privacy Settings -> Apps -> Old versions of Facebook for mobile

This was set to 'Only Me' but I've now changed it to 'Friends' and tested by setting a new status.

[image: Old versions of Facebook for mobile]

Answer (score 0):

The "padlock" icon after a mobile update occurs when you update your status from a mobile. You cannot remove it as such. If you want it to not appear, you should be logged on to www.facebook.com from your mobile and see facebook in its real form instead of m.facebook.com. If you are using an application to be logged into facebook, facebook will know that you are using it on mobile and place the icon. If you are updating your facebook status via sms, then also facebook will know and place the icon. The only way is to be logged into www.facebook.com from a mobile browser.

And about some of your friends being able to see your status updates and some not - that's insane, I do not think it is possible. The only thing that I can come up with is that you have messed up your privacy setting on facebook or may be the app you use to log on to facebook from mobile allows you to set privacy settings separately and you have messed it up there.